# How do i make a table sort-able in javascript without using JQuery

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-table

I just want a simple way for the columns of my table to be sort-able. I'd using the method outlined in this guide http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/ which I have seen other people here use ([Auto sort the table using sorttable.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886497/auto-sort-the-table-using-sorttable-js))

I can't use any JQuery for any of this.

In the website there are 3 steps

- Download the Javascript library
- Include the Javascript library, by putting a link to it in the HEAD of your page, like so:

  ```
  <script src="sorttable.js"></script>
  ```
- Mark your table as a sortable one by giving it a class of "sortable":

So i did the following:

- As far as downloading the javascript library, I'm not really sure what they mean by that. I took the file that he had (http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js), and made my own link to it on my site in my file manager (http://www.enviroptics.com/Matt/js/sorttable.js)
- Which leads me to the second step. I tried doing:

  ```
  <script src="http://www.enviroptics.com/Matt/js/sorttable.js"></script>
  ```

  But I don't really know how to do that in my fiddle because i dont use the script tag, i just work in the js window. So then i tried using w3schools, along with the above code.
- Lastly, i gave the class sortable to my table

Can someone take a look at either my fiddle: (https://jsfiddle.net/msirkin/duw5nyqe/6/) [relevant code on lines 99-102 and 176 of Js, and line 7 of HTML]

or my w3schools: (http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=F08E6AHSU5Q3) for some reason when i add the src to the script tag the whole table disappears

I'm sure it's an easy fix for someone with a little more experience than me, thanks!

Comment: Because of CORS, you need to either serve the javascript file with an https link, or insert it with some other method

Comment: Create a new .js file, copy the content of the sorter file to it, save it, then use this site to host it: http://yourjavascript.com/

Comment: @Bálint  idk much about https other than the s means the page is secure. What if the link that i want to open is just an http link. "https://www.enviroptics.com/Matt/js/sorttable.js" and "https://www.enviroptics.com" don't exist. Also I dont even know how to put that src in my javascript for the fiddle. Am i supposed to be using the setAttribute to set the src?

Comment: @Bálint okay, ill give that site a try

Comment: @Bálint   They emailed me saying add this coded to my website: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourjavascript.com/726029128431/sorttable.js"></script> But i don't really know where to add that in my fiddle

Comment: Where you originally put the oder script

Comment: I didnt put any src or script tag anywhere in my fiddle because i dont know where it goes. Unless you mean to do it in w3schools?

Comment: in the head element.